# Google Chrome userscript doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, userscripts

I've written a small userscript for Google Chrome. It works pretty fine, until I call a function `initTimer()` There is no such a function in my script, but it is in a script in the page on which my userscript runs, but anyway there's an error `initTimer() is not defined`. I've tried to write `window.initTimer()`, but it says `Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'initTimer'`. So how can I make it work?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because userscripts are typically sandboxed from the rest of the browser environment, userscripts cannot interact with the scripts running on the page itself, nor can scripts running on the page interact with userscripts, for security reasons.

You'll have to do script injection for this, by creating a `script` element in the page itself containing the code you want to execute.

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.innerHTML = 'initTimer();';
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

The problem with this, which may or may not break your script, is that the injected code will have no way of communicating directly with the code in the sandbox, so you'd either have to inject *all* of your code, or use an alternative method to communicate if you need to.

Comment: Thank you! I've injected the whole script to the webpage and now it works! Thanks again!